# Using TRAMP for accessing Nextcloud

Tags: tramp

I would like to use TRAMP to access my Nextcloud server. The TRAMP documentation regarding Nextcloud is a bit cryptic and requires some 'Online Accounts' application, which seems to be available only under Gnome and KDE. Has anybody managed to use TRAMP with other session managers or even independent of them to access Nextcloud? I could imagine, that it should also be possible to use information from authinfo.gpg or similar.

Comment: If this was resolved, could you please add an Answer for other users to benefit from?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't resolved this. I don't use Gnome, so my impression was, that it would be too much trouble to get this to work.

Comment: I don't *think* you actually need to have Gnome itself in order to use gvfs.  I don't know specifically what's needed though.

Answer (score 1):

Tramp uses GVFS (Gnome Virtual File System) and GOA (Gnome Online Accounts) for accessing nextcloud servers. If both are not available on your local host, you cannot use Tramp for a nextcloud connection.

Comment: I have set up an account in 'Gnome Online Accounts', but I could not get this to work. I tried accessing '/nextcloud:user@host', but the tramp debug messages show There is no Online Account ‘/nextcloud:user@host:’. I can see the account in the gnome-control-center, but Emacs seems not to find it. Is there anything I can do to find out, why this doesn't work?

Comment: Well, debugging is not possible with SX comments. Please contact us via the Tramp ML <tramp-devel@gnu.org>.